# Image is not displaying in mPDF

Tags: html, image, pdf, mpdf

mPDF is not displaying image which name has special character like - Foto-I-fur-AM-1ä.jpg

I am getting error - mPDF error: IMAGE Error ([http://localhost/MPDF57/examples/Foto-I-fur-AM-1ä.jpg](http://localhost/MPDF57/examples/Foto-I-fur-AM-1%C3%A4.jpg)): Could not find image file.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: May the "ä" in the filename cause the problem?

Answer (score 1):

try

```php
$mpdf = new Mpdf();
$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
```

Could also be due to not having GD library installed locally.